# RealityKit Loading Models Keep Original Shapes of the Model and Make it Less Bouncy

Tags: realitykit

I am using the following code to load a model in RealityKit.

```
 receiveValue: { entity in
                    
                    let floor = ModelEntity(mesh: MeshResource.generatePlane(width: 5, depth: 5), materials: [OcclusionMaterial(receivesDynamicLighting: true)])
                    floor.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
                    floor.components[PhysicsBodyComponent.self] = PhysicsBodyComponent(massProperties: .default, material: .default, mode: .static)
                    
                    let anchor = AnchorEntity(raycastResult: result)
                    entity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
                    
                    let collisionComponent = CollisionComponent(shapes: [ShapeResource.generateBox(size: [0.2, 0.2, 0.2])], mode: .default)
                    entity.components[CollisionComponent.self] = collisionComponent
 
                    entity.components[PhysicsBodyComponent.self] = PhysicsBodyComponent(shapes: collisionComponent.shapes, mass: 10.0, material: .default, mode: .dynamic)
                    
                    entity.position.y = 0.5
                    
                    anchor.addChild(floor)
                    anchor.addChild(entity)
                    arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
                }
```

The model is loaded when I tap on the screen and it performs a ray-cast and adds the shoe on the ground. The problem is that I had to specify the shape in CollisionComponent. So even though the shoe is not a cube but because of generateBox it acts like a cube.

Also when it falls it bounces multiple times I want it to behave like a shoe.